# Why is VMware workstation adding keystokes when I type?

Tags: development-environment, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I'm having a very strange problem.  I'm remote desktoping into a system and running vmware workstation there(its a pretty powerful server and wanted to test a cluster on it).  My problem is when I type it repeats the characters.  For example, instead of root, it types rooot or rrrrrrrooooot. So I can't get into my linux systems

I thought this was due to my connection(remote desktop to a server in another country) but when I open notepad it works fine.  This issue appears to only be related to vmware workstation.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your .vmx file:

```
keyboard.typematicMinDelay = "2000000"
```

This will increase the delay before a keypress is repeated to 2 seconds (2000000 microseconds). This should effectively remove your problems with keyboard repeat for your VM. A side effect is of course that it will make it harder for you to use keyboard repeat...

For more information on how to edit your .vmx file, [see this guide on vmware.com](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1714).

EDIT: Also, [here's a more detailed guide to the solution I provided](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=196).

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, that seemed to work.  But one question, its still not letting me in(but my typing is fine now) so I suspect when I set the default password during the install it messed up my keystrokes.  I'm wondering is there a way to set this option as the default so when I launch a new instance it takes this right from the start?

Answer (score 0):

`keyboard.typematicMinDelay` did not work for me.  I had to adjust the key repeat settings in Gnome on the Linux guest:

```
xset -r
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

To increase the delay time, execute one of the following commands:

```
xset r rate 1000
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 1000
```

(the default the value is usually 500, so you can try different values higher than that).